# Android - Same buttons accross multiple layouts

Tags: java, android

I'm writing my first android app and having some trouble.  I have 4 layouts, each with their own xml file and the same 4 buttons at the top of each screen.  The 4 buttons should simply switch between the 4 layouts, but I can't get it to work.  When the app laucnhes, I can click on any 1 button and it works, but I can't click on another one after that to change the layout again.  The buttons are defined in each xml and I'm thinking that is the problem.  Is there a better way to do this?  Something similar to frames in html?

Answer (score 5):

Hey you'll be wanting a Tab Layout right?

[image: Tab Layout]

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

http://www.techwavedev.com/?p=14

[Android Tab Layout tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915425/android-tab-layout-tutorial)

Comment: That would be my best guess too, nice links!

Comment: Mark answered, this helps others find the same result! It's the green tick  to the left of the answer just below the number and arrows. Clicky. GL